# C# How compare 2 values in Object from Dictionary by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am trying to get an object from dictionary with minimum value and bool, Whether it was checked or not.

```
var minTile = (from i in openedGridTIle  let  minCost = openedGridTIle.Min(m => m.Value.TotalCost)                           
where i.Value.TotalCost == minCost select i).FirstOrDefault();
```

With one request through LINQ it works fine, I can get the object with minimum value, how can I get object with minimum value if it was not checked?

My try:

```
var minTile = (from i in openedGridTIle  let  minCost = openedGridTIle.Min(m => m.Value.TotalCost)                           
          where i.Value.TotalCost == minCost select i).FirstOrDefault();
          //&&
          //(from b in openedGridTIle let chekVal = openedGridTIle.Select( f => !f.Value.Walkable )
          //    where b.Value.Walkable = chekVal select b).FirstOrDefault());
```

But it is not working? Is it possible to do in two requests ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to find value based on minimum `TotalCost` and later you are trying to add a check against a `bool` field. You can shorten your original query to:

```
var minTile = openedGridTIle.Values
                      .OrderBy(m=> m.TotalCost)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Later if you want to add a check against a bool value then you can do:

```
var minTile = openedGridTIle.Values
                      .OrderBy(m=> m.TotalCost)
                      .FirstOrDefault(f=> f.Walkable == false);
```

Or

```
var minTile = openedGridTIle.Values
                      .OrderBy(m=> m.TotalCost)
                      .FirstOrDefault(f=> !f.Walkable);
```

You can also do that in two requests like:

```
var minTile = openedGridTIle.Values.Min(r=> r.TotalCost);

var items = openedGridTIle.Values
                          .Where(r=> r.TotalCost == minTile 
                                     && !r.Walkable);
```

You will get an `IEnumerable<T>` in items. If you are only interested in a single item then you can add `FirstOrDefault()` to items, or replace `Where` with `FirstOrDefault`, since it will accept a predicate as well.

Comment: Thanks you mean, i must use  two serial separated request?

Comment: @x5reunion, :), you don't have to. The second code snippet should give you the result.